# Can't install driver for TP-Link 802.11ac USB on Ubuntu 23.04 (kernel 6.2.0-36-generic)

Tags: apt, software-installation

I am using Ubuntu 23.04

I run this command at terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install git dkms
```

But I am getting this error:

```
Error! One or more modules failed to install during autoinstall.
Refer to previous errors for more information.

     * dkms: autoinstall for kernel 6.2.0-36-generic
       ...fail!
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms exited with return code 11
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic (--configure):
     installed linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
    Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-6.2.0-36-generic
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Please add `dkms status` to your question through [edit].